# Durable subscriber with logstash jms input plugin

Tags: elasticsearch, jms, logstash, activemq-classic

I need to index documents from an ActiveMQ broker into Elasticsearch. I am using logstash for that purpose, with the JMS input plugin (that is build upon jriver-jms). As I need to ensure that every document stored in a topic of the ActiveMQ broker gets into Elasticsearch, I want to establish a durable subscription with logstash. How can I do that ? There is no parameter such as "durable" in the JMS input plugin configuration.

Answer (score -1):

You can add jms.clientID parameter (http://activemq.apache.org/connection-configuration-uri.html) into connection URL

Comment: Unfortunately, the clientID does not make the subscription durable.